# Missing Right parenthesis error with `=>`

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am getting the error after writing the below code for a simple insert..select stmnt . I am confused as there seems nothing wrong with syntax .

```
INSERT INTO dimension_tab(FACT_1_ID,FACT_2_ID,FACT_3_ID,FACT_4_ID,SALES_VALUE)
SELECT TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 3)) AS fact_1_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 6)) AS fact_2_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 11)) AS fact_3_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 11)) AS fact_4_id,
       ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 100), 2) AS sales_value
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 1000;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: very interesting question.. I faced problem on similar lines wherer order by was part of select statement. I think same problem here. I dont see anything wrong in syntax and I tried few things like putting "select * from" before actual select query. Created view and tried to insert through view but none is working at my enviornment. Will be back to see if anyone can find solution for this. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE is

```
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
  low  IN  NUMBER,
  high IN  NUMBER
)
```

So you can use like this...

```
INSERT INTO dimension_tab (FACT_1_ID,FACT_2_ID,FACT_3_ID,FACT_4_ID,SALES_VALUE)
SELECT TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  3)) AS fact_1_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  6)) AS fact_2_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  11)) AS fact_3_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  11)) AS fact_4_id,
       ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  100), 2) AS sales_value
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a valid syntax, but as you are using oracle 10g it will not support `=>`, So you'll have to replace `(low => 1, high => 3)` with `(1, 3)`.

Try like this,

```
INSERT INTO dimension_tab
SELECT TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  3)) AS fact_1_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  6)) AS fact_2_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  11)) AS fact_3_id,
       TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  11)) AS fact_4_id,
       ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value( 1,  100), 2) AS sales_value
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```